# Calculating tidal ranges

Tags: r

I have a data frame that contains the following info on tides. I am trying to write a function that takes four params (low.max, hi.max, hi.earliest, hi.latest). For example, show me all days where a low is 2ft or less, the hi is 6ft or less and the hi occurs between 10am and 4pm. Right now I am looping through rows to do this (kind of have hi.max - low.max working with that), but I'm new to R and assume there is a more R-like approach.

```
  date      day  time       ft      cm     H/L
2013/01/01  Tue 07:03 AM    8.1     247     H
2013/01/01  Tue 12:49 PM    5.1     155     L
2013/01/01  Tue 05:30 PM    5.7     174     H
2013/01/02  Wed 12:03 AM    0.5     15      L
2013/01/02  Wed 07:33 AM    8.1     247     H
2013/01/02  Wed 01:40 PM    4.4     134     L
2013/01/02  Wed 06:32 PM    5.3     162     H
2013/01/03  Thu 12:42 AM    1.4     43      L
2013/01/03  Thu 08:03 AM    8.1     247     H
2013/01/03  Thu 02:33 PM    3.5     107     L
2013/01/03  Thu 07:46 PM    4.9     149     H
```

Adding the dput output:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(15706, 15706, 15706, 15707, 
15707, 15707, 15707, 15708, 15708, 15708), class = "Date"), Day = c("Tue", 
"Tue", "Tue", "Wed", "Wed", "Wed", "Wed", "Thu", "Thu", "Thu"
), Time = c("7:03 AM", "12:49 PM", "5:30 PM", "12:03 AM", "7:33 AM", 
"1:40 PM", "6:32 PM", "12:42 AM", "8:03 AM", "2:33 PM"), Pred.Ft. = c(8.1, 
5.1, 5.7, 0.5, 8.1, 4.4, 5.3, 1.4, 8.1, 3.5), Pred.cm. = c(247L, 
155L, 174L, 15L, 247L, 134L, 162L, 43L, 247L, 107L), High_Low = c("H", 
"L", "H", "L", "H", "L", "H", "L", "H", "L")), .Names = c("Date", 
"Day", "Time", "Pred.Ft.", "Pred.cm.", "High_Low"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I tried so far for the hi/lo part, independent of time:

```
  tides <- read.csv("TideData.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  for (i in 1: nrow(tides)){
    if (tides[i, 6] == "L" & tides[i, 4] <= low.max 
        & tides[i+1, 6] == "H" & tides[i+1, 4] <= hi.max){

      #deal with last iteration being out of bounds / write out to a df

    }
```

Comment: Please also include machine-readable data for the example.  Use `dput(head(dat, 11))` where `dat` is your data frame.  Then it will be clear how your data actually look.

Comment: Post the code that you've tried so far that isn't working for you. The "for example, show me" makes this sound like a homework assignment that you're wanting someone to do for you, and we don't do that here. :-)

Comment: Added the dput - thanks. Not homework - I just surf at a very tide-dependent spot and I got skunked again today :-).

Comment: So the correct answer for the data offered is "none of the above"? I have a coded answer but it gave no days which have a "H" < 6 at a time < 4PM and that's what my eyeball test is telling me, too.

Comment: Thanks DWin. You're right my example data doesn't work with the time requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Subsetting data is a very basic operation in R and is well described, for example in the R manual [An Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Index-vectors).

Assuming your data is called `x`, use the subset operator `[` to specify the rows you want to keep:

```
x[x$Pred.Ft < 2, ]

        Date Day     Time Pred.Ft. Pred.cm. High_Low
4 2013-01-02 Wed 12:03 AM      0.5       15        L
8 2013-01-03 Thu 12:42 AM      1.4       43        L
```

Or the high tides only:

```
x[x$Pred.Ft > 6, ]

        Date Day    Time Pred.Ft. Pred.cm. High_Low
1 2013-01-01 Tue 7:03 AM      8.1      247        H
5 2013-01-02 Wed 7:33 AM      8.1      247        H
9 2013-01-03 Thu 8:03 AM      8.1      247        H
```

To combine logical statements, use `|` for `OR` or `&` for `AND`. So, to get the set of low as well as high tides in one step:

```
x[x$Pred.Ft > 6 | x$Pred.Ft < 2, ]


        Date Day     Time Pred.Ft. Pred.cm. High_Low
1 2013-01-01 Tue  7:03 AM      8.1      247        H
4 2013-01-02 Wed 12:03 AM      0.5       15        L
5 2013-01-02 Wed  7:33 AM      8.1      247        H
8 2013-01-03 Thu 12:42 AM      1.4       43        L
9 2013-01-03 Thu  8:03 AM      8.1      247        H
```

---

To get the high tides in spring tide only, try this. Since you know that each Low is followed by a High, you can calculate the difference in tide levels with `diff`, and then return only rows where the difference is higher than a threshold:

```
x$Tidediff <- c(NA, diff(x$Pred.Ft))
na.omit(x[x$Tidediff > 6, ])

        Date Day    Time Pred.Ft. Pred.cm. High_Low Tidediff
5 2013-01-02 Wed 7:33 AM      8.1      247        H      7.6
9 2013-01-03 Thu 8:03 AM      8.1      247        H      6.7
```

Comment: Thanks -- I get the general idea of subsetting. I am trying to find the cases where a low of a certain max height is *followed* by a hi of a certain max height, all in a certain range of times during the day. The data is in chronological order.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `by` function to process within records having the same Date value:

```
L.lt.2 <- by(tides, tides$Date, FUN= function(d) d[
                          d$High_Low=="L" & d$Pred.Ft <= 2,  "Date",drop=FALSE])
H.lt.6.b.4 <- by(tides, tides$Date, FUN= function(d) d[
               d$High_Low=="H"     &     d$Pred.Ft <= 6    & 
               as.POSIXct(d$Time, format="%H:%M %p") <= 
                                           as.POSIXct("4:00 PM", format="%H:%M %p"), 
                                                             "Date", drop=FALSE])
intersect(L.lt.2, H.lt.6.b.4)
#[[1]]
#character(0)
```

Didn't bother to put in the additional time requirement since the data was not constructed to support testing of condition. Leaving as an "exercise" since it would only involve adding an additional logical vector to the `[i, ...]` -selection operation. (It would have been better to have constructed an example that had at least one date where the target was satisfied.)